# Date not showing correctly as I input

Tags: php, date, strtotime

```
if ($this->request->is('post')) {
    $this->Operation->create();
    if(!isset($this->request->data['Operation']['date_alarma'])){
        $this->request->data['Operation']['date_alarma']= date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime($this->request->data['Operation']['date_alarma'].' '.$this->request->data['Operation']['alarmA']['hour'].$this->request->data['Operation']['alarmA']['min']));
    }
    else if(!isset($this->request->data['Operation']['date_alarmb'])){
        $this->request->data['Operation']['date_alarmb']= date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime($this->request->data['Operation']['date_alarmb'].' '.$this->request->data['Operation']['alarmB']['hour'].$this->request->data['Operation']['alarmB']['min']));

    }
    else if(isset($this->request->data['Operation']['date_alarmcc'])){
        pr($this->request->data['Operation']['date_alarmcc']) ;
        $a= date('Y-m-d',strtotime($this->request->data['Operation']['date_alarmcc']));
        pr($a); die;
    }
```

The output showing like this

**30/05/2015**
**1970-01-01**

May I know why? The date I enter is 30/05/2015 at field `date_alarmcc`

Answer (score 1):

**strtotime()** will interpret this format as **m/d/Y**, not **d/m/Y** and thus will return **false** because there is no 30th month.

```
echo (int) strtotime('05/30/2015');
// 1432969200
echo (int) strtotime('30/05/2015');
// 0
```

However, **strtotime()** will evaluate **d-m-Y**:

```
echo (int) strtotime('05-30-2015');
// 0
echo (int) strtotime('30-05-2015');
// 1432969200
```

Unix timestamps represent the number of seconds passed from **1970-01-01** so this represents the timestamp **0** because of the **false** return value from **strtotime()**.

If you always want to use the **d/m/Y** format.  You could easily replace `/` with `-` using **str_replace()**:

```
$date = str_replace('/', '-', $date);
```

Thus it will be evaluated as **d-m-Y** correctly.

Comment: i want change format it to Y-m-d
it will be like 2015-05-30
but in my output show as default date .

Comment: Well, you can't use strtotime, atleast not by itself with d/m/Y format.

Comment: I wrote why it goes to the default date.  strtotime() is returning false because there is no 30th month.  False evaluates to the integer 0, 1970-01-01 represents the unix timestamp 0.

Comment: yes im understand we can change it '-' to '/' but what i want to do is want to change the date format which is from 30th may 2015 to  2015-05-30.

Comment: The code should like this 
date('Y-m-d',strtotime($this->request->data['Operation']['date_alarmcc'])

Comment: but the result it show to default date not what i enter it

Comment: I think you need an understanding of the functions you are running.  It seems maybe you copy pasted and don't know anything about the code you are running.